# Run build on change but don't checkout in Hudson

Tags: hudson

I have kind of an interesting problem...

So I'm trying to run a build every time I see a change on a directory in my SCM in Hudson. However, I don't need to pull the directory to run my script. Is there any way to check if there's a change in a directory, but don't pull it?

In addition, there is another directory which I do need to pull from Hudson at the same time. So basically I want something like:

On change of directory A or B:
    pull directory B only
    run script

I was told there was functionality like this in Hudson, but I can't find it. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: How is it that you don't need directory A?  It may help folks give good suggestions.  Also, what SCM are you using?

Comment: I suppose this is a very specific situation, and it really makes no sense without an example. I have a script that I want to run in directory B that I use to automate the compiling of code. However, I need to compile this code on multiple hosts, so my script remotes into each one and re-compiles the codes there. so I need to detect changes in directory A, which contains my code, but I don't want to waste space on my machine when it doesn't need the code.

Hope that helps! Also I'm using perforce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to install the [FSTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin) for this functionality. To what the wiki pages show this is supported in Jenkins, I am not sure about Hudson compatibility.

Comment: That looks like it would do exactly what I'm asking. I did some more looking around and found that Hudson has a configuration for Perforce that does exactly what I'm looking to do, so I just used that. However, your answer works for any SCM, so I would consider it as the real answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, I was able to accomplish this with just Hudson and Perforce.

When using Perforce as the SCM (don't know about the others) there is a 'Use View Mask' checkbox. Checking that give you the ability to choose which directories/files in Perforce to poll without actually pulling those files. For example, I had in my view:

//depot/my_script

I didn't want my script to run automatically when I had a new version, so I put it int o the "Poll Exclude File(s) text box:

//depot/my_script

Which pulls the latest version of my script. Then I checked the Use View Mask checkbox and put:

//depot/my_code_to_compile/

into the View Mask box.

To make Perforce poll for changes, I just checked the "Poll SCM" in build triggers and then made it check every minute. (by inserting "* * * * *" into the Scheduler box)

So to sum up, with the variables set as above, my Hudson job had the following behavior:

check for changes every minute

On changes to //depot/my_code_to_compile/, the Hudson job will run

On changes to //depot/my_script, nothing will happen

The job will pull changes to my_script, but will download nothing from //depot/my_code_to_compile/.